# Creating custom chapter-like heading with titlesec and topsection

Tags: titlesec

Trying to format my notes, which are split into a few small modules but part of one subject/course. I want to be able to quickly scroll to a module and review everything from there and separate modules with a custom header describing the module.

First, is it possible to use `titlesec` with `\topsection`? (If not, is it then possible with `section*`)?

If it is possible to use `titlesec`, then can someone help with formatting this - I have a general idea and the code from the `titlesec` documentation but need a little more help in editing it so that it suits the document I am working with.

Here's a general idea of what I want to do:
[image]

Here is the code from the `titlesec` documentation:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]
```

In short:

- Does the code need to be edited much for `section`? If so, what edits are needed?
- How do you edit the "Chapter" text to "Module"?
- To keep track of the number of modules, do I just define a counter?
- Is it possible to have a module title text on the left and a small description on the right?

If someone could give some insight and provide maybe a basic example I can use, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own command `\module` taking as trailing optional argument the description.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\NewDocumentCommand{\module}{O{#2}mO{}}{\chapter[#1]{{#3}{#2}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makemoduletitle}{m}{%
  \makemoduletitleaux#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemoduletitleaux}{mm}{%
  #2\hfill\normalfont\footnotesize\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {\filleft\MakeUppercase{Module} \Huge\thechapter}
  {4ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright\makemoduletitle}
  [\vspace{3ex}\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {4ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{2ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\module{The title} % no description

\module{The title}[This is the description \\ of this module]

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

The accessory code in the example is just to show two titles on the same page. Also `oneside` is used just to make a smaller picture.

[image]

Comment: I up voted in 4 seconds!

Comment: Looks great! Will it work with the article class as well? (Current setup and `titlesec` headings are only compatible with `article` it seems).

Comment: @Revise There is no `\chapter` in the `article` class…

Comment: Yes, but replacing `\chapter` with `\topsection` instead - that's what I'm using to add the headers.

Comment: @Revise Not sure what you mean by `\topsection`

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to explain but `\topsection` provides an unnumbered section at the top level (e.g. in article, it creates an unnumbered `\section` header.

Comment: @Revise Sorry, but I can't follow. Your question is about `\chapter`. Please, ask a new one with ***all*** the needed details.